# Problem in spliting the output of spuser object

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I am assigning the spuserobject.Name in to a string. The out put of this is "FirstName,Lastname, . When i try to split it is not splitting the values can you tell me why?

```
     for (int i = 0; i < grpUserNames.Count; i++)
                    {
                        SPUser user = mySiteWeb.EnsureUser(Convert.ToString(grpUserNames[i]));


                        string email = user.Email;
                        string UN = user.Name;
                        String[] arr = UN.Split(',');
                        String last = arr[arr.Length - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FBA:
  userName = SPClaimProviderManager.Local.DecodeClaim(loginName).Value;
For Windows:
  userName = SPClaimProviderManager.Local.ConvertClaimToIdentifier(loginName);

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your users are in Active Directory or comes from FBA?

If you are in active directory you have to ensure that grpUserNames are in the form "DOMAIN\USERALIAS"

You could try this

```
SPClaimProviderManager cpm = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;

for (int i = 0; i < grpUserNames.Count; i++)
{
    SPClaim userClaim = cpm.ConvertIdentifierToClaim(grpUserNames[i], SPIdentifierTypes.WindowsSamAccountName);
    SPUser user = mySiteWeb.EnsureUser(userClaim.ToEncodedString());


    string email = user.Email;
    string UN = user.Name;
    String[] arr = UN.Split(',');
    String last = arr[arr.Length - 1];
}
```

Hope it helps!